# AdapterDataSetObserver was not registered

Tags: android

**CONSTRUCTION**

I have 2 views: `Spinner` and `AutoCompleteTextView`.

-`AutoCompleteTextView` have `Adapter` that implements `Filterable` and gets data from my API.

-`Spinner` is populated after data from `AutoCompleteTextView` is on the device and is inserted into `SpinnerAdapter`

**ADAPTERS**

```
public class AutoCompleteCityAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable

public class CitySpinnerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter
```

**PROBLEM**

I've created custom `PopulateListener` to populate data from `AutoCompleteTextView` to my `Spinner`.

I enter my data into `AutoCompleteTextView`, I get the result, `Spinner` is getting populated via my `PopulateListener` until whole operation is repeated.
When I delete my text and enter new one I get `AdapterDataSetObserver was not registered` when I call `setAdapter()` on my `Spinner`.

**CODE WHERE EVERYTHING BLOWS UP**

```
autoCompleteCityAdapter.setPopulateListener(new AutoCompleteCityAdapter.OnPopulateListener() {
        @Override
        public void setCityData(ArrayList<String> cityData) {
            if (cityData != null) {
                CitySpinnerArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new CitySpinnerArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityData);
                spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_item);
                selectSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); //this throws the error
            } else {
                ((CitySpinnerArrayAdapter)selectSpinner.getAdapter()).clear();
                selectSpinner.setAdapter(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

Two words about code above.

if -> is when `CityData != null` therefore there was response from API so I can set `Adapter` on my `Spinner`.

else -> is when `CityData==null` therefore no response from API which means that text was removed or edited. `Spinner` needs to be cleared because its data is invalid at that right moment.

**POPULATE CUSTOM LISTENER THAT IS SET ON AutoCompleteCityAdapter**

```
public interface OnPopulateListener {
    public void setCityData(ArrayList<String> cityData);
}

public void setPopulateListener(OnPopulateListener populateListener) {
    this.populateListener = populateListener;
}
```

**ERROR INFO**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver@53c1ce78 was not registered.
        at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
        at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:103)
        at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:371)
        at com.test.calculator.ui.fragments.CalcFormFragment$3.setCityData(CalcFormFragment.java:285)
        at com.test.calculator.ui.adapters.AutoCompleteCityAdapter$1.publishResults(AutoCompleteCityAdapter.java:120)
        at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

**===================EDIT=====================**

Code in response to pskink.

```
  autoCompleteCityAdapter.setPopulateListener(new AutoCompleteCityAdapter.OnPopulateListener() {
        @Override
        public void setCityData(ArrayList<String> cityData) {
            if (cityData != null) {
                if (selectSpinner.getAdapter() != null) {
                    ((CitySpinnerArrayAdapter)selectSpinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    CitySpinnerArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new CitySpinnerArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityData);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_drop_down_item);
                    selectSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                }
            } else {
                ((CitySpinnerArrayAdapter)selectSpinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: tried to selectSpinner.setAdapter() once and then notifyDataSetChanged() after "data set changed" ?

Comment: I've tried that but my Spinner is not getting updated.

Comment: post the whole code then

Comment: With notifyDataSetChanged() or normal one?
What classes would you like to see?

Comment: with notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @pskink added code in Edit.

Comment: its hard to tell, here you the have working code with ACTV and Spinner, try to adapt it to your needs and tell what went wrong http://pastebin.com/kmepV8NS